# divs with display: table-column have size=0

Tags: css, css-tables

I am trying to create something similar to this:

[image]

I tried with the following code, but I see nothing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #table {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: table;
        }

        #left {
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            display: table-column;
        }

        #right {
            width: 70%;
            height: 100%;
            display: table-column;
        }

        #left_1, #left_2, #left_3, #right_1 {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        #left_1 {
            background-color: green;
            height: 40%;
        }

        #left_2 {
            background-color: red;
            height: 30%;
        }

        #left_3 {
            background-color: lightgray;
            height: 30%;
        }

        #right_1 {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="left_1">left_1</div>
        <div id="left_2">left_2</div>
        <div id="left_3">left_3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="right_1">right_1</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to successfully use `table-row`, but I can't get `table-column` to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with flexbox.

The needed changes in CSS

```
#table {
    display: flex;
}
#left, #right {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#left_1, #left_2, #left_3, #right_1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

updated jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1mew6hqj/2/

[Check this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for flexbox to learn how it works.

Comment: How do I get the text to be centered both horizontally and vertically as in my bitmap?

Comment: To align content flex has justify-content, justify-items, align-content, align-items. I have edited the answer, check it out.

Comment: I am marking this as answer because, even if I was asking for `display: table-column`, I think that `flex` is a valid (or better) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Michael Coker, but here is another possibility.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#table {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.row {  display: table-row;  }

#left_1,
#left_2,
#left_3,
#right_1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#left_1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40%;
}
#left_2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30%;
}
#left_3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 30%;
}
#right_1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left_1">left_1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left_2">left_2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left_3">left_3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="right_1">right_1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: I hope this isn't for a responsive site...

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I have now, which works well on horizontal mobile devices. I was experimenting with bot `flex` and `display:table` for the very reason you mentioned: to make it responsive :)